# How to remove the last <li></li> using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
  <div id="q">
    <ul><li>
    <table><tr><td>Question 1</td><td><input type="text" name="question1" size="60" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Answer:</td><td><input type="text" name="answer1" size="8" /></td></tr>
    </li></ul>
</div>

<input class="btn" id="addquestion"  type="button"  value="Add Question" />
<input class="btn" id="removequestion"  type="button"  value="Remove Question" />
<script>


 $('#addquestion').click(function() {
 var $question_number = $('#q li').size() + 1;

   $html='<li><table><tr><td>Question '+$question_number+'</td><td><input type="text" name="question'+$question_number+'" size="60" /></td></tr>\
   <tr><td>Answer:</td><td><input type="text" name="answer'+$question_number+'" size="8" /></td></tr></li>';
  $('#q ul').append($html);
   });

  $('#addquestion').click(function() {
$('#q li:last').remove();
}); 
</script>
```

$('#q li:last').remove(); doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: And AC said, "LET THERE BE LIGHT!"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to remove the last `li` element inside `#d`, you can simply use the [`:last`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/last) selector:

```
$('#q li:last').remove();
```

If you want to remove every last `li` child of it's immediate parent (`ul` elements if you have more than one), you can use the [`:last-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild) selector:

```
$('#q li:last-child').remove();
```

Comment: Maybe because you have two click functions on the same element `#addquestion`, one adds the `<li>..</li>` and the second one removes it immediately.

Comment: Oops, what I'm trying to say is change your second function: `$('#removequestion').click(function() { $('#q li:last').remove(); });`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var lis = $('#q ul').children(); // get all the children
$(lis.get(lis.length-1)).remove(); // remove the last one
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It says "lis.get(lis.length-1).remove is not a function"

Comment: It still doesn't work. The error message is "lis.get(lis.length-1).remove is not a function"

Comment: Ugh. Try that, I think it needed to be jQuery-ized with `$()`.

Comment: Doen't work. I think the problem lies in the syntax of $(lis.get(lis.length-1)).remove();

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Can you do `.remove()` on some specific element you got with `$()`? Also try checking the value of `lis.get(lis.length-1)`.